# Not to allow more than 1 character in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

currently I am working on a page which is having cross-word puzzle. Hence, I am in the situation to stop typing more than one character in content editable div. Please note that this is for epub development. Hence, I can't use input tag. Please guide me in this regards.

I tried following script in div itself. But it is not allowing me to type any character after I used backspace.

```
onkeypress="return (this.innerText.length >= 1 ? false : true )"
```

Since, I have due to the client in another one day. It will be great, if you solved this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXkaq/1/)

Use a callback to keypress. (Works for backspace, delete)

```
$('div').on('keypress',function(){
     return ($(this).text().length<1)
});
```

Also you might need to handle copy-paste

```
$('div').on('paste',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**[Demo with paste handled](http://jsfiddle.net/fXkaq/2/)**

Comment: It fails in firefox. Refer the comment by Teemu

Comment: I have updated the working code, working in all browsers

Comment: @shaunakde, I used your following code and it sounds good in safari. Since, I am developing epub for ipad. This is enough. $('div').on('keypress',function(){
     return ($(this).text().length<1)
});

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

To allow other control keys, you should handle the `onkeydown` event instead, but note that at the time `onkeydown` is triggered, the typed key has not been appended to the text field. So instead of checking for text length being 1, we'll check for it being 0.

```
$('div').keydown(function(e){
   return $.inArray(e.which, [8, 46, 37, 39]) > -1 || $(this).text().length == 0;
});
```

`8` is keycode for <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, `46` is key code for <kbd>Delete</kbd>, `37` and `39` are keycodes for <kbd>Left arrow</kbd> and <kbd>Right arrow</kbd> respectively.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/zw99K/2/)

A sub note about using `return false;` to cancel the event, normally we should use `e.preventDefault()` because `return false;` also means `e.stopPropagation()` is called.